# Pass parameters from Processor to Writer

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have a step with a reader, a processor and a writer for writing data to files.

Depending on the type of data processed, I want to write it to a different location.

How can I specify at runtime from the reader or processor where the data should be written?

Example(maybe a silly one):

read(items)->process(items)>write(to apple folder)

read(items)->process(items)>write(to tomato folder)

I cannot know in what order the items come, nor their type. I only find this out in the reader and processor, but the writer again has no idea what it handles.

Is there a way to make this happen(something like reader.getWriter().setAttribute() or by using some kind of session)?

Comment: Well, should we assume that all the same items in a given commit-interval are to be written in the same directory? Or should every item in a same commit be possibly written in a different directory one by one?

Comment: @ArnaudPotier It is assumed that all items in a commit-interval belong to the same directory. This is 100% sure.

Comment: @ArnaudPotier Also, please check my comment to Michael Minella's answer. It might make things a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Composition is a strong theme in Spring Batch.  In this case, you'll want to implement a composite `ItemWriter` that delegates to child `ItemWriter`s based on where it needs to be written.  You have two options, implement your own or use the `ClassifierCompositeItemWriter` provided by Spring Batch.  It will really depend on what the logic is for your selection process.  You can read more about the `ClassifierCompositeItemWriter` in the documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/support/ClassifierCompositeItemWriter.html

One important note when using this approach is that the delegate `ItemWriter`s won't be automatically registered as `ItemStream`s.  You'll need to do that manually.  You can read about how to do that here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/htmlsingle/#delegatePatternAndRegistering

Comment: Unfortunately what you are suggesting is nearly impossible. Let me offer more details. The reader is actually a crawler - it searches each folder from the hard disk and reads the files inside. The processor analyses the information and then it passes to the writer the needed data to continue. The writer should put everything out in the source folder(from which the job read in the first place). The thing is, I have a lot of folders and I cannot make a writer for each one. Hopefully you understand my need now. Sorry for not providing enough details in the first place. Thank you!

Comment: That doesn't really change my answer.  `FlatFileItemWriter` implements  `ResourceAwareItemWriterItemStream` which would allow you to implement a wrapper `ItemWriter` to set the resource based on the input.  There are a couple caveats however.  First would be that it could really only be set once per chunk so you'd need to set your chunk size appropriately (potentially 1).  The other caveat would be that you'll take a large performance hit as you open/close files to be written to.